# Does the speed bonus from the monk feature Unarmored Movement stack with the bonus from the barbarian feature Fast Movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, monk, stacking, barbarian

At level 5, barbarians get a bonus of +10 feet to their speed while not wearing heavy armor from [Fast Movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#FastMovement).

At level 2 and increasing as they level, monks get a bonus to their speed when not wielding a shield and not wearing armor from [Unarmored Movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#UnarmoredMovement).

Therefore, do these 2 features stack for a bonus of +20 feet to the speed of a character with 7 levels (5 Barbarian, 2 Monk)? Or can you get only one bonus, whichever is higher?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 12):

### If the barbarian is completely unarmored and isn't wielding a shield, the conditional for both bonuses is met, and they stack to +20.

Movement bonuses aren't AC calculations. Multiple bonuses from separate effects and attributes are generally cumulative unless the text explicitly indicates they aren't or another distinct rule prohibits stacking. No such rule exists for bonuses to your speed.

---

As a quick few examples of other rules that *do* prevent stacking: Temporary HP explicitly never stack with themselves; you may only ever use one formula at a time to calculate your AC (*mage armor* doesn't stack with a monk's Unarmored Defense because it has its own formula); and no matter how many times you get advantage (or disadvantage) on a roll, you only ever roll one extra die from either.

Comment: Also, features with the same name don’t stack.

Comment: AC calculations are also not bonuses, but calculations.  ;)

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, the speed bonuses do stack because they are from game features with different names

Bonuses generally do stack in 5e. Unlike in *Pathfinder* or 3e, there is no rule in 5e that bonuses of the same type do not stack. By default bonuses always stack, *as long as they are caused by features that have different names*.

This exception to stacking is on p. 252 DMG, Combining Game Effects:

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But **when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them** - the most potent one - apply while the durations of the effects overlap. (...) Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items. See the related rule in the "Combining Magical Effects" section of chapter 10 in the *Player's Handbook.*

Because the Barbarian’s class feature is called Fast Movement and the Monk's is called Unarmored Movement, the two bonuses are not caused by game features with the same name, so they do stack, and your Barbarian/Monk will enjoy a speed bonus of +20 feet.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that a increase to Str through Gauntlets of Ogre Power will stack with the increase to Str from a Belt of Hill Giant Strength? They have different names, but I'm sure that is not the case because they both apply a Str modifier, which is the same affect. In which case Monk and Barbarian speed improvements would not stack because they both apply a Movement buff.

Comment: @SiBrit those two (and all similar) items don't *increase* your strength by +X, they *set* your strength to =X if it's lower than X. So, you'd only get the benefit of the better one. Much like AC calculations.

Comment: @Adeptus. Ahh. My bad. I had forgotten they specifically set your stat. I suppose blah blah of Protection (cloak, rings, etc.) won't stack because they are all "of Protection"?

Comment: @SiBrit Those will stack, the full name is different. They cost attunement though.